# How pagination works in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Can you please tell me how pagination works in case I do not specify any "sort" field?

In my query, if I do not specify "sort" field and then try pagination using "from" plus "size", how does elasticsearch return data? is there any chance of returning duplicated records?

es query:

```
GET index1, index2/_search?pretty
{
  "from": 10,
  "size": 20,
  "_source": {"includes”:[“name”, “type”]}, 
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "org_id":{
                     "value”:”1234456767257”,
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            },
            {
        "range" : {
          “Timestamp” : {
            "from" : 1596545417000,
            "to" : 1597035223465,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   }
}
```

In this above query, I did not specify any "sort" field. Will this ensure of returning unique results if I increase "from" after each call? If Yes, HOW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the documents are sorted by `_score:desc`, that's probably not what you want if you're constantly indexing new documents.

I would definitely add a [sort clause on `_doc`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html), that's the only way to guarantee you're going to get unique results.

```
{
  "from": 10,
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": "desc"     <--- add this
    },
    {
      "_doc": "asc"        <--- and this
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Also if you consider paginating beyond `from: 10000`, you need to [leverage `search_after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after)

Comment: Okay. This is good one. Yeah, I noticed that sometimes `_score` have same value. So it will be problematic. Adding  "_doc" will help definitely. Got it. Thanks @Val

Comment: If you add `_doc:asc` you need to add `_score:desc` as well otherwise you're not going to get ranked results

Comment: Yeah, Just tried without `_score:desc` and I'm getting `"_score" : null`.
And, if I add `_score:desc` I'm getting `"_score" : 15.326606`

Answer (score 1):

By default sorting results from different shards is done by coordinating node that accepts the request from client.

Also by default the sorting is done on _score field.

Yes without sort field, the results are always unique considering that the cluster is stable and that replicas are aligned to primary shards.

Comment: Okay, Got it. It's fine if its based on "_score". On a few occasions, I have seen that some documents have same score. 
For example, 
"_id" : "a2ed6343-8829-4b17-896e-168dc0e3236c__4d81048b-1e0e-40af-8e11-0342fc0459f2",
        "_score" : 15.32563

"_id" : "a2ed6343-8829-4b17-896e-168dc0e3236c__a49e4cad-490a-44b2-807e-b76d1945bea5",
        "_score" : 15.32563

So, how will it return the next page if the scores are same?

Comment: No it won't, _score alone is not sufficient. See my answer

Comment: I am not aware how by default elasticsearch keeps track of pagination offsets. But recommended way is to provide sort fields for unique pagination results. If I get to know how the default pagination with same scores are handled, I will update here.